# Is the use of [private], [protected] and [public] encouraged or discouraged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Do the tags:

- [private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private)
- [protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protected)
- [public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/public)

even make sense?

According to the tag wikis, they're supposed to be used in context of OOP.

> Private is a way of encapsulation in object-oriented programming.

---

> `public` is an access-specifier in object-oriented languages; it indicates that all objects have access to the `public` field or method.

---

> `protected` is an access specifier in object-oriented languages. When the members of a class are `protected`, there is restricted access to these members for other classes.

I cannot really imagine anyone excelling at questions about `private`, `public` or `protected` methods, fields or classes specifically or looking for information on just those. All three also seem to appear together on some questions:

- [In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/q/215497/1407656)
- [What is the difference between public, private, and protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4361553/1407656)

There is the exception of questions, in which one of those modifiers behaves in a manner unexpected by a poster. Or questions which concern the consequences of using a specific access modifier.

- [How do I test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34571/1407656)
- [How do you unit test private methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/250692/1407656)

These ones also look like they could be tagged with [private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private) but they seem to be doing just fine without it:

- [JavaScript private methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55611/1407656)
- [Initializing private static members](https://stackoverflow.com/q/185844/1407656)

[encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encapsulation) and [access-modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-modifiers) seem to cover more scenarios and they're more descriptive of the purpose. They also fit a broader range of potential solutions to problems with using whichever specific modifier in various OO languages. If a question concerns a specific modifier, it also has it mentioned in the body and is likely enough to come up in a search anyway.

Perhaps the three tags should be synonymized with [access-modifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-modifiers) or removed altogether? Should I be using them in my questions?

Comment: I'm in favor of synomization; it dovetails nicely with what that tag is about and doesn't feel too language-specific.

Comment: Scanning through the [private] tag, it does get used appropriately sometimes but not very often.  It is most typically used as a combing word, like [private] + [inheritance] or [private] + [function] or [private] + [variable], etcetera.  The tags getting reordered turns it pretty nonsensical.  It doesn't slow anybody down, the answer rate is in fact extraordinary high at 85%.  The concept is simple to understand so getting an answer isn't special.  It is not a problem at all, no need to turn it into one.

Comment: And indeed we do have [private-inheritance] (seems reasonable) and [private-functions] (don't know) tags for those combinations.  (Thankfully no [private-variable].)

Comment: Depends on what your goal is. The undeniable fact is that the overwhelming majority of people coming to SO to get an answer are people looking for a quick fix and haven't done much research on the subject. I'm not talking about the people actually asking the questions (the bad questions are a smaller subset of the same crowd) but ppl who hop on the site looking for answers, primarily teenage and college students looking for a quick fix. And since (arguably) most of these kids don't even know that public and private are modifiers, perhaps keeping them separate would prevent more copy questions.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom searching for `[private*]` reveals a [lot more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/private+or+privatekey+or+private-members+or+private-methods+or+private-messaging+or+private-pub+or+private-constructor+or+private-inheritance+or+privatefontcollection+or+private-class+or+private-functions+or+privateobject.invoke+or+private-header+or+private-network)

Comment: at least there are [tag:private-ryan], [tag:private-benjamin] tags

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: Presumably the former will be 'saved'?

Answer (score 17):

For me it's a clear No! As @Makoto commented it is too specific and mostly not really a tag valuable for grouping. No user would be interested especially in questions tagged `public` or `private`.

To replace those tags by `access-modifier` or (imho) better `visibility` would be more useful.

Comment: Not `visibility`, that sounds more like it's for UI in general, CSS in specific

Comment: @Izkata right, missed that